# How to make icecast read stream from an executable on demand

Tags: icecast, transcoding

I am using **udpxy + icecast** to convert a number of multicast webradio streams into unicast streams.  Unfortunately the multicast streams are mpegts while my clients only support mp3 streams.
I know I can transcode the incoming streams using ffmpeg and publish them directly on my icecast server using something like:

```
  ffmpeg -i <incoming url> -codec:a libmp3lame -ab 256k -ac 1 -content_type audio/mpeg -f mp3 icecast://source:<pwd>@<icecastserver>/<mountpoint>
```

However I have about 150 incoming radio stations and at most 10 simultaneous clients so I do not want to be transcoding all stations all of the time.  Is there a way to configure icecast to read the stream from stdout of another executable? So when a listener connects to a new webradio mount, icecast would start the executable and uses the output as a stream.

I tried using on-connect to start the ffmpeg command above but then I have a chicken-and-egg problem as the icecast mount needs to exist to run on-connect but then the ffmpeg command cannot create it (or it is too slow to start)
I tried creating a script in the webroot but icecast just sends out the content in stead of executing it (yes, it was executable).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: have you looked at the url-auth and listener-add? https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url

Comment: @TBR but that's client side, no?  I don't see how I can use that to influence the source side?

Comment: A client connection coming in will invoke a HTTP request to an URL. You can use this to start the source client for that mountpoint and then release the waiting client to it. Or you run it async by making the request, returning and parking the client on a fallback and overriding it back one the source connects.

Comment: Here is a project I made following TBR's approach: https://github.com/jeremysanders/ice_launcher